# How to find all invalid document based on jsonSchema validator?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

One of the new feature in MongoDB 3.6 is jsonSchema validator. I can create a collection with an validator like:

```json
{
  "validator": {
    "$jsonSchema": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "bsonType": "string",
          "description": "name"
        },
        "age": {
          "bsonType": "int",
          "minimum": 10,
          "maximum": 30
        }
      },
      "required": ["name", "age"],
      "bsonType": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

But what if the collection already existed with some documents, that don't fullfill the validation schema? How can I found out all invalid documents based on the validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`$jsonSchema` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/) to find relevant documents.

For example, using the `mongo` shell:

```js
// Retrieve the current validator for the "students" collection
var schema = db.getCollectionInfos({ name: "students" })[0].options.validator

// Find any documents not matching the schema
db.students.find({ $nor: [schema] })
```

Similarly, you can use the `$jsonSchema` query operator to confirm expected matches before adding or updating the validator for a collection:

```js
var schema = {
  $jsonSchema: {
    properties: {
      name: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "name",
      },
    },
    required: ["name"],
    bsonType: "object",
  },
}

// Find documents matching schema
db.students.find(schema)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I want. The `db.students.find({$nor: [ schema ]})` returns all documents dont fullfill the jsonSchema. But it doesn't tell the detailed information. Is there any way I can get a detailed information? For example, whether the `age` of a document is not between 10 and 30.

Comment: @ZhaoYi As at MongoDB 3.6, the server validation isn't able to report the details of which properties didn't match. However, there are a number of client libraries/validators that may provide more informative errors (see: [JSON Schema Implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators)). For a MongoDB server improvement, upvote & watch [SERVER-20547: Expose the reason an operation fails document validation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.

Comment: do you know what jsonschema version mongo server is using for validation?

Comment: @ZhaoYi MongoDB 3.6 supports most of JSON Schema `draft-04` aside from JSON references & pointers, and adds some extensions for BSON types. See Extensions & Omissions in the documentation for the [`$jsonSchema` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/).

Answer (score -2):

As `MongoDB` documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) To specify JSON Schema validation, use the [$jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema) operator in your validator expression.

For example, the following example specifies validation rules using `JSON` schema:

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {   --- jsonSchema validation
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            gender: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               minimum: 0,
               description: "must be a double and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Or As I am able to see in your code , the jsonSchema validation.

```
"validator" : {
                "$jsonSchema" : {  ---jsonSchema
                    "properties" : {
                        "name" : {
                            "bsonType" : "string",
                            "description" : "name"
                        },
                        "age" : {
                            "bsonType" : "int",
                            "minimum" : 10,
                            "maximum" : 30
                        }
                    },
                    "required" : [
                        "name",
                        "age"
                    ],
                    "bsonType" : "object"
                }
            }
```

In addition to JSON Schema validation, MongoDB supports validation with query filter expressions using the [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors), with the exception of [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near), [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere), [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text), and [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where).

> but what if the collection already existed with some documents don't
> fullfill the validation creterial?

Validation occurs during `updates` and `inserts`. When you add validation to a collection, **existing documents** do not undergo validation checks until modification.

**For Existing Documents**

The **`validationLevel`** option determines which operations MongoDB applies the validation rules:

1. If the **`validationLevel`** is **`strict`** (the default), MongoDB
   applies validation rules to all inserts and updates.
2. If the **`validationLevel`** is **`moderate`**, MongoDB applies validation rules
   to inserts and to updates to existing documents that already fulfill
   the validation criteria. With the moderate level, updates to
   existing documents that do not fulfill the validation criteria are
   not checked for validity.

For example, create a contacts collection with the following documents:

```
db.contacts.insert([
   { "_id": 1, "name": "Anne", "phone": "+1 555 123 456", "city": "London", "status": "Complete" },
   { "_id": 2, "name": "Ivan", "city": "Vancouver" }
])
```

Issue the following command to add a `validator` to the contacts collection:

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "contacts",
   validator: { $jsonSchema: { --- jsonSchema validation
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "phone", "name" ],
      properties: {
         phone: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         },
         name: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         }
      }
   } },
   validationLevel: "moderate"   --- validationLevel moderate , With the moderate level, updates to existing documents that do not fulfill the validation criteria are not checked for validity
} )
```

The contacts collection now has a validator with the moderate validationLevel:

If you attempted to update the document with `_id` of `1`, MongoDB would apply the validation rules since the existing document matches the criteria.
In contrast, MongoDB will not apply validation rules to updates to the document with `_id` of `2` as it does not meet the validation rules.

To disable `validation entirely`, you can set **`validationLevel`** to `off`.

> How can I found out all invalid documents based on the validator?

**For Accept or Reject Invalid Documents**

The `validationAction` option determines how MongoDB handles documents that violate the validation rules:

1. If the **`validationAction`** is **`error`** (the default), MongoDB
   rejects any insert or update that violates the validation criteria.
2. If the **`validationAction`** is **`warn`**, MongoDB logs any
   violations but allows the insertion or update to proceed.

For example, create a `contacts2` collection with the following JSON Schema validator:

```
db.createCollection( "contacts2", {
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {  ---jsonSchema validation
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "phone" ],
      properties: {
         phone: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         },
         email: {
            bsonType : "string",
            pattern : "@mongodb\.com$",
            description: "must be a string and match the regular expression pattern"
         },
         status: {
            enum: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         }
      }
   } },
   validationAction: "warn"  --- validationAction is warn, MongoDB logs any violations but allows the insertion or update to proceed.
} )
```

With the **`warn`** **`validationAction`**, MongoDB logs any violations but allows the insertion or update to proceed.

For example, the following insert operation violates the validation rule:

```
db.contacts2.insert( { name: "Amanda", status: "Updated" } )
```

However, since the `validationAction` is `warn` only, MongoDB only logs the validation violation message and allows the operation to proceed:

```
2017-12-01T12:31:23.738-0500 W STORAGE  [conn1] Document would fail validation collection: example.contacts2 doc: { _id: ObjectId('5a2191ebacbbfc2bdc4dcffc'), name: "Amanda", status: "Updated" }
```

> **Important Note :** You cannot specify a validator for collections in the `**admin**`, **`local`**, and **`config`** databases.
>
> You cannot specify a `validator` for **`system.*`** collections.

For your further reference with jsonSchema validation [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00), [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation/?include_text=1) and [here](http://json-schema.org/)